# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to  connect to an elasticsearch database using spark and my code snippet looks like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Spark").getOrCreate()
reader = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.read.metadata", "true").option("es.nodes.wan.only","true").option("es.port","9200").option("es.net.ssl","false").option("es.nodes", "here-ip-adress")
df = reader.load("my_index")
```

When calling `df = reader.load("my_index")` I get the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.load.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:191)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 20 more
```

There are some other solutions here on stackoverflow, but for some reason none of them have helped. I am using Spark version 3.2.0, Scala version 2.12.15 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_312) and running the code with `spark-submit --packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:6.1.0`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show us your build.sbt if you use sbt?

Comment: I am not using sbt :( I am actually using python and importing the elasticsearc-hadoop package from maven as JARS as this is the only alternative I found to use elasticsearch hadoop with python @DariuszKrynicki

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using different Scala version binaries.

please check again you imported spark compiled with the right Scala version.

according to maven dependencies, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/6.1.0

`elasticsearch-hadoop:6.1.0` depends on the spark compiled with Scala 2.11, so you should choose a compatible spark version.

Comment: If I am running spark-shell it says I am using Scala 2.12.15, so it should be fine I guess, or am I missing something?

Comment: Might the issue be because of the elasticsearch-hadoop:6.1.0 package that I imported? I also tried with elasticsearch-hadoop:7.17.0

Comment: I think maybe you already point it, according to maven dependencies both `elasticsearch-hadoop:6.1.0`  and `elasticsearch-hadoop:7.17.0` depend on spark compiled with scala2.11

Comment: Thank you! I downgraded to spark 2.4.7 and this solved the issue with Scala :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here in 2023,

I had same error with `ElasticSearch` version `8.6.1`, `PySpark 3.1.2` and [ElasticSearch official](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/hadoop) JARs. Official JARs only include `elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-8.6.1` with support for `scala 2.11`.

Solution: Instead, I downloaded the correct [JAR with scala 2.12](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12/8.6.1/jar) and everything runs smoothly ...

```
pyspark --jars elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12-8.6.1.jar

>>> reader = spark.read.format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql').option('es.nodes', 'ES_IP').option('es.port', 9200)
>>> read_df = reader.load('ES_INDEX')
```